# how to calculate logarithm of symbolic function in python?

Tags: python, sympy, logarithm

I have a symbolic function in python( obj_rev). I want to calculate the logarithm of this function. I use the following code:

```
obj_rev = x_1**2 - 2*y_1+1
g_ = obj_rev
l1 = (tau/2) * sp.log(g_)
print(l1)
```

When I run the code, I get the following error:
"TypeError: cannot determine truth value of Relational"

I change my code to:

```
x = Symbol('x')
y = Symbol('y')
expr=x**2+y**2
print(sp.log(expr))
```

But the error still remains

Comment: What is `obj_rev`? Can you post a complete minimal example to reproduce your issue?

Comment: @Keldorn:  obj_rev = x_1**2 - 2*y_1+1

Comment: Show the actual error with traceback.  A `Relational` is a `sympy` expression like `x<0`.  We get this kind of error when using a Relational in a python context that requires a simple True/False such as an `if` or `and`.  I don't see any of that in this code example.

Comment: Your code runs fine on my machine. Sympy 1.10.1